# Get the first 5 and last 2 chars of a string

Tags: php

I have a string like this: `$str="moolti1"` and I want this to be cut into two strings or something like that.
I need `"m00lti"` and `"1"`. As the first part is always the same length (6), isn't there a method like `$pre=$str[0:5]`?

Comment: You mean you couldn't find [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) in the PHP docs?

Comment: I think @m00lti wants the method to return both parts, not just one substring

Comment: If it's both parts in a one-liner because using `substr()` twice is too hard; then `list($firstPart, $secondPart) = str_slit($str, 6);`

Comment: @MarkBaker That will fail for strings of length >= 13.

Comment: @Amber - then let Moolti use 2 substrings..... I've got better things to do with my time than provide answers to cover every single possible circumstance for something that's as basic as `substr()`. OP gives no indication that his strings will be longer than 13 characters; and the subject line of the question suggests otherwise

Comment: @MarkBaker I wasn't saying you should keep providing answers; I was just saying that your original comment was the better one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str="moolti1";

$parts = str_split($str, 6);
```

Comment: Great answer if end part is never more than 6 characters - with string moolti143243342343242 you would get 3 parts but if you know the end part won't be greater than 6 characters then this is best answer! I have +1 this as it is elegant solution if suitable

Comment: thanks! i just didn't know the `list()` function, thanks to @MarkBaker for the comment on my post!

Answer (score 2):

```
$str="moolti1";

$start = substr($str, 0, 6);

$end = substr($str, 6);
```

You may find I have a number out somewhere as I always ALWAYs get confuzzled with my start indexes and lengths but this should give you what you need.

Comment: The `strlen($str) - 1` part is unnecessary; `substr()` automatically goes until the end of the string if the length argument is omitted.

Comment: good point - its my vb.net habits that always come into php - will ammend and thanks for catch

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's `substr()` function

```
$str = 'moolti1';
$first_five = substr($str, 0, 5);
$last_two = substr($str, -2);
```

More info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: great - but what if it is moolti2134 - this wouldn't work!

Comment: Your question needs to be rephrased. It sounds like what you're really looking for is how to separate numbers from integers in a string.